# how to include 2 files with same name?

Tags: c++

I am working in ubuntu, I have a folder that contains a subfolder. in the first folder i have a name.h file. in subfolder i have again a name.h file. the thing is that i need both the headers. the problem is the fact that both headers have the same name. i receive errors saying that a specific function was not declared in this scope. how to resolve this error? isn't there a way to specifiy to a specific method, variable what header to use ? is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just because you're using a Ubuntu PC doesn't mean you have to tag every question `ubuntu`. Your questions are not about Ubuntu. Do you also tag every question "air" and "the world around me"?

Comment: Just `#include` the header with the correct relative path. I don't understand the problem?

Comment: @Tomalak: the meaning of relative paths in `#include` directives is implementation-defined, so "Ubuntu" is somewhat relevant. I agree it's probably not worth a tag, though. In practice, you would occasionally need to use a different relative path in different implementations - had a PITA once where if you include "b/foo.h" from "a/src.cpp", then in one implementation `#include "bar.h"` would find "b/bar.h", in another it would only look in `a/` and the include path.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It's relevant only in that it _may_ help to guess at which toolchain he's using; further than that, that he's on Ubuntu imbues no magical, unique behaviour to the environment. Besides, my comment was a general one, relating to almost all of the OP's recent questions.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Sounds lame. I'd always expect the "current" directory to be searched, if only for reasons of sanity.

Comment: @Tomalak: true, but Ubuntu has a strong preference for a particular default C++ implementation. If a questioner is running Windows under VMWare on Ubuntu, though, and describes that as "Ubuntu" then they deserve useless answers. Clang on Ubuntu maybe less clear-cut case. And it was a bit lame, but as far as it was concerned `a/` was the current directory and it recursively processed includes from there. Fix was to always give names relative to something on the include path.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Generally a wise approach anyway, I guess.

Comment: @Tomalak: wise, but inconvenient ;-) It meant that little components either had to know their own place in the hierarchy (making them less independent), or else every single one had to be in the include path (a niggle in the build process, and the more you have in there the more opportunity for a name clash which means the file isn't found at all). That said, as long as namespace hierarchy matches filesystem, it wasn't that big a deal for all includes to be relative to the root of the source being built, since it's information that the file "knows" anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop: On the contrary. Little components do _not_ need to know their own place in the hierarchy. They all assume they're at the project root if you always specify include paths relative to that.

Comment: @Tomalak: they did need to know. In component "utils/stuff/b", for "foo.h" to include "bar.h" either it needs to include it as "utils/stuff/b/bar.h" (that is, b needs to know its place in the hierarchy, the utils/stuff part, in order to find its own files), or else "utils/stuff/b" needs to be in the include path (which causes problems if any other little component has a file called bar.h). As I say, the first option boils down to the same issue as choosing a namespace or an include guard name, but at the time it was an extra portability surprise to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, something like this :

```
<some dir>
  -> <sub1>
       header.hpp
  -> <sub2>
       header.hpp
```

This is resolved by telling the compiler to search in the common folder for the headers (in the above case ) and including like this :

```
#include "sub1/header.hpp"
#include "sub2/header.hpp"
```

Comment: thx for the answer. where should i write <some dir> -><sub1>..and so on? in the .cpp file? it is ok if i write <folder1>...or should i give the whole path? i want to create a .a and work with it

Comment: and one more question. if i have a method whousl i write sub1/method? or how should i specify from what header to define the method,class and so on?

Comment: @marryy: Nowhere - it's visualization of the directory structure.

Comment: @marryy: If the headers define symbols with the same name but differently, you are out of luck. But if whoever wrote them had at least a bit of sanity, each of the headers defines the symbols either in namespace corresponding to the directory name it is in, or with a similar prefix.

Comment: thx. and what about the methods? how to tell with what header to work/

Comment: @marry If possible, header names should be unique. I am not sure what do you mean with methods

Comment: @marryy For methods, you need to use different namespaces

Answer (score -1):

If they have the same header guard, then there'll be problem, otherwise it should work.

Comment: My header file have header guard simillar to their name. If the both header have the same header guard, then after preprocessing one of them will be discarded and cause the problem of undefined variable/function etc...

Comment: But that's not what this question is about, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I thought he already knew how to include the file correctly by specifying the subfolder when including.

Comment: @KienTruong I know this is late, but I upvoted this, because this was my issue. In CLion, header guards are automatically generated for us, and hence, I did not catch this quickly.